# How to convert an input type="file" to .net fileupload?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have existing legacy code that is using a standard form.

I would like to in the page init event of the code behind grab a handle to this input type="file" element, and convert it to a .net fileUpload object.

Is this possible? Without rewriting the whole form?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Not looking for an example of how to handle the upload processing, just looking for the entry point - how to get a reference to the input type=file and treat it as a .net fileupload object. - Thanks again.

I was thinking along the lines of :

```
Dim myControl1 as FileUpload = FindControl("myFileElement")
```

Would this work if I could sort out the casting issue?

Comment: If you're allowed to add `runat='server'` and `id` attributes then this `html` tag becomes HtmlServer control.

Comment: you say "without rewriting the whole form" but its just replacing one tag `<input type="file" />` for `<asp:FileUpload ID="upload" />`. I don't see the problem.

Comment: @JL. if its not a postback, then you won't get the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would the `Files` property off the `HttpRequest` class suffice?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.files.aspx

Comment: @JL. - it is available since .net 1.1